# Service Injection to test controller jasmin

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

**Newest Update**

My service or factory can still not be found.

```
'use strict';

/* jasmine specs for controllers go here */

describe("Backpage Controller", function(){

   describe('Root Ctrl', function() {

    var scope, ctrl, myService; 

    beforeEach(module("backpageApp")); 

    beforeEach(inject(function(Data, $controller, $rootScope) {
      myService = Data; 
      scope = $rootScope.$new(); 
      ctrl = $controller("RootCtrl", {$scope:scope}); 
    }));

   it('should set the default value of orderProp model', function() {
      expect(scope.orderProp).toBe('rent')
   });

   it('should create "listings" model with 10 listings', function() {
      expect(myService.listings.length).toBe(10)
   });

  });
});
```

This is the newest error.

```
Chrome 32.0.1700 (Mac OS X 10.8.4) Backpage Controller Root Ctrl should create "listings" model with 10 listings FAILED
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
        at null.<anonymous> (/Users/judyngai/Desktop/Jan2014/newback/trynewversion/minibackpage/test/unit/controllersSpec.js:24:32)
Chrome 32.0.1700 (Mac OS X 10.8.4): Executed 2 of 2 (1 FAILED) (0.284 secs / 0.058 secs)
```

my services.js file contain this, I am using the angular seed project.

```
angular.module('backpage.services', [])
  .factory('Data', function($resource) {
    return $resource('data/data.json');
});
```

my app.js file is this

```
var backpageApp = angular.module('backpageApp', ['ui.router', 'ngResource', 'ngRoute','backpage.services', 'backpagecontrollers']);
```

---

I am very new to angular js. I am trying to write a jasmin spec that test my RootCtrl.

I created a service to share between controllers

```
angular.module('backpage.services', [])
  .factory('Data', function($resource) {
    return $resource('data/data.json');
});
```

I injected the module above to my application level module.

The RootCtrl has a 'Data' parameter given to its function so the scope object can access the shared data.json fetched by $resource.

I set this to the Data in the Root Ctrl

```
$scope.listings = Data.query();
```

Now I am having trouble figuring out how to inject the service I created to my spec written in jasmin.

My Jasmin file currently looks something like this

```
describe("Backpage Controller", function(){

   describe('Root Ctrl', function() {

    var scope, ctrl; 

    beforeEach(module("backpageApp")); 

    var $injector = angular.injector(['backpageApp']); 
    var myService = $injector.get('backpage.services');

    beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $httpBackend) {
      scope = {}; 
      ctrl = $controller("RootCtrl", {$scope:scope}); 
    }));

   it('should set the default value of orderProp model', function() {
      expect(scope.orderProp).toBe('rent')
   });

   it('should create "listings" model with 10 listings', function() {
      expect(myService.listings.length).toBe(10)
   });

  });
});
```

I am currently getting this error when I run the jasmin test

```
Chrome 32.0.1700 (Mac OS X 10.8.4) Backpage Controller Root Ctrl encountered a declaration exception FAILED
    Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: backpage.servicesProvider <- backpage.services
```

I have taken a look at the testing examples on angular js official documentation, the sample uses

```
$httpBackend
```

in the jasmin code to grab the json file but the `$httpBackend` doc says its use with $http service but I am using resource.

Also the `data.json` contain 10 listings of advertisements.

any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When you run `beforeEach(module("backpageApp"));` angular-mocks loads all the dependencies automatically and allow you to inject them as in regular applications (*not tests*)

You also need to create a scope with `$rootScope`:

```
var scope, ctrl, myService; 


beforeEach(module("backpageApp")); 


beforeEach(inject(function(Data, $controller, $httpBackend, $rootScope) {
  myService = Data;
  scope = $rootScope.$new(); 
  ctrl = $controller("RootCtrl", {$scope:scope}); 
}));
```

Comment: I am getting this `TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
     at null.`

Comment: I am getting this new error now  `TypeError: Object #<Scope> has no method 'new'` I have also updated my answer.

Comment: I think `myService` is still undefined.

Comment: What do you mean by undefined? Is it injected or throwing a provider error?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out I should just use  $httpBackend from angular js to fetch the data.json file.

I have this as a variable `httpBackend`

I injected this into *$httpBackend*

```
 httpBackend.when('GET', 'data/data.json').respond([{id: 1 }, {id: 2}, {id:3}, {id:4}, {id:5}, {id:6}, {id:7}, {id:8}, {id:9}, {id:10}]);
```

and flush it back out

```
 httpBackend.flush();
```

for testing purposes